# Restful API method for getsystemstatus

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api

Currently we are changing the SOAP API to Restful API in our chase email program. Can any one restful endpoint to access the [getsystemstatus](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getsystemstatus.htm) method? Currently we consuming this method with SOAP API. Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently the REST API does not do everything that the SOAP API does, and below i provided a link with the major distinctions between the two. Currently there is not any REST route for system status.

[Intro to Marketing Cloud APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm)

REST Routes:

[REST API v1 Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm)